# how to get the sub class property not  super and sub together

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

```
public class ReflectionBase
    {
        public String ParentProperty1 { get; set; }
        public String ParentProperty2 { get; set; }        
    }

    public class Reflection : ReflectionBase
    {
        public String ChildProperty1 { get; set; }

        public Reflection()
        {
            var property = this.GetType().GetProperties();
        }    
    }
```

**Result:**
ParentProperty1
ParentProperty2
ChildProperty1
**I Need:**
ChildProperty1
when i call GetProperties() it gave me all the current class property and the base class also but i just need the current class properties. 
Any Help Please...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [`BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.bindingflags.aspx) to ignore inherited members:

```
var properties = this.GetType().GetProperties(
    BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);
```